# How to migrate data one org to another org

Tags: visualforce, administration

How to migrate data one org to another org. I want to insert all the data of my org into another org. IS a any tool for it.

Comment: Did you do some research before posting this question?

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the following tool which can be very useful to migrate data,

- Apex dataloader
- ANT tool
- Jitterbit cloud dataloader
- workbench.developerforce.com

**OR**

Look into this URL : [Steps to migrate data from one organization to another](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=What-steps-are-needed-to-migrate-my-data-from-one-organization-to-another-1327109132359&language=en_US&type=1)